# Writing a spec for helper with Ruby on Rails and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bdd

I have been writing specs for controllers and models, but I have never written a helper spec. I have no idea where I start.

I have the following snippet in `application_helper.rb`

```
  def title(page_title)
    content_for(:title) { page_title }
  end
```

- How should I write a helper spec on the code?
- Also if there's any open-source Rails app to show good helper testing/specing, do let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RSpec should automatically load classes and modules from your rails environment when you 'describe' them, so a valid helper spec could be:

```
#deleted
```

But remember that bdd is not testing every single method but the behaviour of your application.

edit:

as @Ken said, my spec was not correct, It was definately the wrong way to do it. So I came out with a Request spec solution that I like more than an Helper spec.

```
# inside your helper
def title=(page_title)
  content_for(:title) { page_title }
end

# views/resource/index.html.erb
<% title = "foo" %>

# views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= yield :title %>

# request spec
require 'spec_helper'

describe YourResource do
  it "should output content for title"
    get "/resource"
    response.body.should =~ /<title>foo<\/title>/
  end
end
```

otherwise, if you want to test only the helper behavior (because it's critical or because you don't have any views) @Ken's solution is better.

Comment: Thanks so much for your example. Right BDD is not about covering every method. Most helper methods are touched by Cucumber/Rcov coverage.

Comment: This doesn't test much since content_for returns nil. You should render a page and assert_select "title" contains what you expect.

Comment: This isn't testing a helper, this is testing something else, based on your example it looks like it's testing a view file (e.g. index.html.erb). The helper test should just test the ApplicationHelper#title method itself, without any dependencies on a view or a route/controller.

Comment: I usually don't test simple view helpers, I prefer request specs because they test behaviour over a single functionality.
@KenMayer, I've corrected the code.

Answer (score 21):

From the [rspec-rails docs on Helper Specs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#helper-specs):

> Helper specs live in spec/helpers, and mix in
>   ActionView::TestCase::Behavior.
>
> Provides a helper object which mixes in the helper module being
>   spec'd, along with ApplicationHelper (if present).

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe "#title" do
    it "displays the title" do
      # helper is an instance of ActionView::Base configured with the
      # ApplicationHelper and all of Rails' built-in helpers
      expect(helper.title).to match /Some Title/
    end
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to use [this syntax](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec) when spec'ing helpers

Suppose this is your helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def page_title
    @title || nil
  end
end
```

Then you can spec it with this syntax

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe "#page_title" do
    it "returns the instance variable" do
      assign(:title, "My Title")
      helper.page_title.should eql("My Title")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

It is also possible to include your helper inside the test class as follows:

```
 describe ApplicationHelper do
   helper ApplicationHelper

   it "should work" do
     my_helper_method("xyz").should == "result for xyz"
   end
 end
```

Worked for me with Rails 3.

Comment: Does not work with Rails 7.0.3 and rspec-rails 4.0.2 (gives undefined method `helper`)

Answer (score 1):

Parsing html with regular expressions is really reinventing the wheel. That's way too much work for me: too inflexible, and too error prone. (See this [sarcastic but hilarious and accurate SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1555599) about the reasoning)

If you need to parse the html output by your helpers, you might try the gem [rspec-html-matchers](https://github.com/kucaahbe/rspec-html-matchers). Unlike webrat, it seems to play well with RSpec 3.

Then you can:

```
expect(helper.title).to have_tag('title', text: 'What you expect')
```